# Finding depth of an object in an image given coordinates of object in image frame

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, math

I have images of an object and it has been recognised in the image using Neural network, with open cv, I was able to find coordinates of object in the image, How can I find it's depth i.e distance from the point where camera is, assuming I use two lenses to help in finding the depth.

Comment: you mean you have 2 cameras? You'll need to know the cameras' intrinsic parameters, pixel size and focal length and distortion parameters. Afterwards you can construct the image plane in 3D space, shoot an imaginary ray from the camera projection center through the pixel and calculate where both cameras' rays are about to intersect.

Comment: if you only have one camera you could use monoDepth  or ground plane assumption or if you know the appriximate real world size of your object you can compute the distance/depth again with the camera intrinsics.

Comment: I have multiple camera's pointing at a field and the object moves in that 3-D field and i have to  find the objects coordinates at every point of time, basically, I need to track its movement, I am can recognise the object in the frame using a neural network, so if I can find the depth of the object, I will be able to find  it's 3D coordinates

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is comonly known as "camera calibration".

Have for instance a look here to get the basic idea: 
[Camera calibration With OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/calib3d/camera_calibration/camera_calibration.html)

Good luck

Comment: Thank you, this could help a lot.